# from page *.aspx.cs call javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, button

I want to call a javascript function from my codebehind.
In my button click event handler I have:

```
protected void load_data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dt.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            BindDl();                       
        }
        else
        {
            //if dt.rows.count! = 1 I want to call a JavaScript function where be one alert! how to do?
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page will be helpful for you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx)

```
// Get a ClientScriptManager reference from the Page class.
ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;
Type cstype = this.GetType();
String csName = "MyAlertFunction";

// Check to see if the startup script is already registered.
if (!cs.IsStartupScriptRegistered(cstype, csName))
{
  String jsFunction = "yourFunctionHere()";
  cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csName, jsFunction, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

user scrip manager

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "SHOW_ALERT",  "alert('')", true);
```

where in place of alert you can put your javascript code, next argument true puts in script tags automatically so you dont have to write them.